# Does _mm_load_ps1 require its argument to be aligned?

Tags: c, sse, memory-alignment

A very simple question, but I can't find the answer. MSDN says it expands into `MOVSS` instruction, but that instruction seems to be moving a single `float` from one `xmm` register to another, not loading from memory, so I'm confused.

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple forms of `movss`; including both a reg->reg move and a mem->reg load.  The load form is described in the Intel Architecture Manual as taking a “32-bit memory location”, which does not require special alignment.

Comment: Thank you. On  a sidenote: `_mm_load_ps` also takes a bare pointer but does require alignment.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: ah, you’re right (sorry, I don’t often program with SSE intrinsics — I prefer assembly).  I deleted that remark.